# Me muestra un error al llamar el método "push()" en la clase principal en Java

Tags: java, lista, estructuras-de-datos, pilas, stack

He estado intentan resolver este problema pero simplemente no le llego. Este el código que llevo hasta ahora, tomando el cuenta el ejemplo que me brindaron en la universidad:

```
package pilaDinamica;

import java.util.Stack;

public class pilaDinamica {

    public Stack<Nodo> pila;
    public Nodo inicio;

    public void pilaDinamica() {
        pila = new Stack<Nodo>();
        inicio = null;
    }

    public Nodo Push(Nodo nuevo) {
        return pila.push(nuevo);
    }

    public Nodo Pop() {
        return pila.pop();
    }

    public Nodo Top() {
        return pila.peek();
    }

    public int largo() {
        return pila.size();
    }

    public boolean estaVacia() {
        return pila.empty();
    }

    public int buscar(int id) {
        return pila.search(id);
    }

}
```

En esta clase hice el nodo:

```
package pilaDinamica;

public class Nodo {

    public int id;
   public Nodo siguiente;

    public void Nodo() {

        this.id = 0;
        siguiente = null;
    }

    public void Nodo(int id) {

        this.id = id;
        siguiente = null;
    }

}
```

Este esta es la clase principal hasta el momento, debido a que estoy probando el código:

```
package pilaDinamica;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        pilaDinamica pila = new pilaDinamica();


      pila.Push(1);
       pila.Push(2);
        pila.Push(3);

    }
}
```

El error surge al momento de ejecutar el método push() en la clase principal, no me esta agregando el nodo, ademas de que sin importar el valor que envíe como nodo, no me lo reconoce y el programa se cae y no agrega ningún valor en la pila, hasta ahora ese es el problema que tengo. Gracias, espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: `Push` espera un `Nodo` pero le estas pasando numeros.

Comment: Ya intente  public void Push(Nodo nuevo) {
    pila.push(nuevo);

Answer (score 1):

Está casi listo excepto que tienes:

1. Una confusion entre Metodo y Constructor.
2. Tipo incorrecto del argumento pasado al metodo `Push`.

En la clase `pilaDinamica` deberias quitar el `void` para dejar la firma de constructor.

```
public PilaDinamica() {
    pila = new Stack<Nodo>();
    inicio = null;
}
```

Lo mismo con la clase `Nodo`, necesitas un constructor mas no un método.

```
public Nodo(int id) {
    this.id = id;
    siguiente = null;
}
```

En la clase `Main`, como esta definido en la clase `pilaDinamica`, el metodo `Push` recibe un argumento tipo `Nodo` y no un entero.

```
pila.Push(new Nodo(1));
pila.Push(new Nodo(2));
pila.Push(new Nodo(3));
```

Solo te resta sobre-escribir `toString()` para ver en pantalla el contenido de la colección de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que pasarle `Nodos`, no numeros.

```
package pilaDinamica;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        pilaDinamica pila = new pilaDinamica();


      pila.Push(new Nodo(1));
       pila.Push(new Nodo(2));
        pila.Push(new Nodo(3));

    }
}
```

Comment: Realice este cambio en el método pila: public void Push(Nodo nuevo) {
         pila.push(nuevo);
    }    y en la clase main coloque el código que me recomendaste y me lanza un error.

Comment: ¿Que quieres decir con este cambio?

Comment: public void Push(Nodo nuevo) { pila.push(nuevo); } en la clase pilaDinamica y en agregué el codigo que recomendaste y me lanza un error en ambos, en el metodo push y en la linea pila.Push(new Nodo(1));

Comment: ¿Que error te da exactamente?

Comment: run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at pilaDinamica.pilaDinamica.push(pilaDinamica.java:17)
 at pilaDinamica.main.main(main.java:9) me señala error en dicha lineas, las que te cite anteriormente.

Comment: Eso es porque pila en PilaDinamica es null

Comment: Probando otro método, noté que no me esta funcionando ninguno, creo que tendré que volver a plantearlo. Gracias amigo, por tu ayuda.